# Tornado Routing example

Tags: tornado

In the latest version of Tornado (4.5) there has been the introduction of routing with the class tornado.routing

Can someone please explain how this works and the benefits of this with a practice example. I don't understand the purpose of this.

Comment: It's documented in http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/routing.html. Can you ask a more specific question about what's not clear to you after reading the docs?

Comment: It's a good sampe in https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/routing.py